# While loop for name insert

Tags: python, while-loop

Hi everyone I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a while loop but I'm finding some difficulties,

I've written this code:

```
name = 0
while name != ("1234"):
 name = input("Insert name: ")
 if name == ("1234"):
  print("\nOk")
else:
 print("\nName not entered")
```

But I want the code to be for name entering and every time that you don't write anything the code has to ask you to insert your name until you do it.

Thanks in advance if you can help me :)

Comment: what do You mean You do not enter anything? if You do not press enter it will just stay on the screen

Comment: Also, your `else` is not indented properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question , I understood that you need a code that ask user to enter name until it is entered

```
while True:
    name = input("Insert name: ")
    if name == "" :
        continue;
    else:
        break;
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

just add space to else and to print function after else because in python spaces are so important

```
name = 0
while name != ("1234"):
 name = input("Insert name: ")
 if name == ("1234"):
  print("\nOk")
 else:
  print("\nName not entered")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want, but maybe that's you want ?

```
name = 0
while name != "1234" or name == "":
    name = input("Insert name: ")
    if name == "1234":
        print("\nOk")
    else:
        print("\nName not entered")
```

Compact version with a ternary operator

```
name = 0
while name != "1234" or name == "":
    name = input("Insert name: ")
    print("\nOk" if name == "1234" else "\nName not entered")
```